# Backup registry in VC++?

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, registry, backup

I've been trying to backup the Registry in VC++ using the RegSaveKeyW function.
I found out recently that this function can't backup some keys - eg the HKLM\Security hive since it needs System / "SeTcbPrivilege" privilege, and elevating to System account is difficult.
We are trying to replicate how [ERUNT](http://www.larshederer.homepage.t-online.de/erunt/) backs up the Registry.  We're not sure how it does this, but one idea we have is that perhaps it uses [VSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy).

I'ld like to know the different options in VC++ for backing up registry keys, their pros and cons. Eg Option 1 VSS - Pros... Cons... Option 2... etc.
Then I can look into them more and hopefully come across the method that ERUNT uses to Backup the Registry Hives.

Please advise?

Comment: I would expect that any tool that backs up the Security hive has sufficient privilege to do so. At least I hope there isn't some backdoor way to get to the Security hive without correct privileges [or, if there is, at least it's not officially published on sites like StackOverflow...

Comment: Backing up the registry with processes running is an iffy proposition.  But doesn't hold a candle to the *real* problem, actually using that backup to restore the registry.  Use system restore points.

Comment: @Hans: The big difficulty there is that system restore points cannot be restored from outside the OS in Windows XP. And also that system restore can be turned off by the user.